# Python - twisted reactor - difference between callLater and callFromThread from threading perspective

Tags: python, twisted

I have a python class which uses `twisted reactor`. When it gets SIGINT; it calls `reactor.callLater(0,sys.exit)` from signal handler function.

What I observed is with `callLater(0, sys.exit)` my process takes some time to exit, around 30 seconds, if i replace this with `reactor.callFromThread(sys.exit)` then I see my process is exiting immediately.

I am not able to understand reason behind this behavior, why `callLater` taking time and with `callFromThread` its not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because a signal handler interrupts the normal flow of execution on the main thread.  Any code you call from a signal handler has to be able to deal with program state from an arbitrary position in the execution of the program.

For example, consider this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 1

    def bar(self):
        x = self.x
        self.x = self.y
        self.y = x

    def sigint(self):
        print(self.x + self.y)
```

In the normal course of execution, you would never expected `sigint` to print anything except for `1`.  But if `sigint` is installed as a signal handler and a signal is delivered in between the lines `self.x = self.y` and `self.y = x` then it will see `self.x` equal to 1 and `self.y` equal to 1 and print `2`.

For this reason, you can generally only rely on APIs that are marked as "signal safe" or "reentrant safe".  These APIs are implemented in a way that takes into account the way signal handlers are invoked and avoid tripping over surprising intermediate internal states.  For example, a signal safe version of the `Foo` class might look like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 1
        self._bar_lock = threading.Lock()

    def bar(self):
        with self._bar_lock:
            x = self.x
            self.x = self.y
            self.y = x

    def sigint(self):
        with self._bar_lock:
            print(self.x + self.y)
```

Twisted's `callFromThread` is signal safe for essentially the same reason it is thread-safe.  The API may be invoked from a non-main thread at essentially any point and encounter the same potentially inconsistent intermediate internal states.  For `callFromThread` to work as a way to signal the reactor thread from another thread, it must account for the possibility of these intermediate internal states - and it does so.  By virtue of this, it is also safe to use inside a signal handler.

Comment: @Jeane-Paul Calderon - Thanks for your response, so you meant using callLater() from signal handler function may cause data race and due to which we see such issues? correct?

Comment: Yes.  Unlike callFromThread, callLater is neither thread-safe nor reentrant safe.